# vPro and Intel Core i7-950 (LGA 1366)

Tags: chipset, vpro

What chipset do I need in order to use intel Active Management Technology (part of vPro technology)?

Is it supported by X58? Wikipedia says only about Q57 but it's LGA 1156 sockets and also I would prefer using some better chipset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the vPro 2010 platform, the chipsets are Intel Q57, QS57, OR QM57 Express Chipset. You can find processor and chipset details in this paper: http://communities.intel.com/docs/DOC-5583

Michele Gartner / Community Manager / Intel vPro Expert Center

Comment: Hey Michele welcome to the Super User community. You don't need to append your name onto answers.  A good place to put that is on your profile page.  Just FYI ;)

Answer (score 3):

It appears that vPro is only usable on Q57 based chips, which means you can't use 9xx series i7's, only 8xx series.